# Conditional exchangeability when conditioning on continuous variable

Tags: causality, exchangeability, counterfactuals

Conditional exchangeability is often introduced in a simple setting with a binary outcome, binary treatment, and binary confounding variable. In this setting, exchangeability holds *within* strata of the binary confounding variable. But what if the confounding variable is continuous? I have not yet seen a detailed explanation of this scenario.

Suppose the outcome is death, $Y \in (0,1)$, treatment is medication, $D \in (0,1)$, and the confounding variable is severity of disease, $X \in (0,1)$. Exchangeability holds iff those who took the drug are exchangeable with those who did not take the drug, i.e., the potential outcomes must be jointly independent of the treatment status,

$(Y^1,Y^0) \perp D$

Because we have confounding, $X$, exchangeability holds *within* strata of severity of disease. Thus, we have conditional exchangeability,

$(Y^1,Y^0) \perp D|X$

where $(Y^1,Y^0) \perp D$ holds within $X=0$ and $X=1$.

How would this presentation be extended when the confounding variable is continuous? Say blood pressure, $B$,

$(Y^1,Y^0) \perp D|B$

I believe this is when stratification breaks down and regression is more appropriate (Morgan & Winship, 2015), but it would be nice to have a simple explanation that extends the presentation above.

Comment: I think you're confusing an assumption with a method of estimating. The assumption of conditional exchangeability has nothing to do with whether the confounder is categorical or continuous. The estimation method (i.e., stratification vs. regression) will depend on this, but that is unrelated to the assumption (i.e., it applies to any conditional expectation, whether it is causal or not). Talking about the absence of confounding "within strata of $X$" is just a way to make the assumption more intuitive, but that is not precisely what "conditional on" means.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I could have stated my question better. I know the assumption is unrelated to whether the confounding is categorical or continuous. I imagined a scenario where I would present this (as I have been presented before), and someone asks how the example above changes if the confounding variable is continuous. Perhaps this is easier in a regression framework. Could you elaborate how to explain "conditional on" in this context? Intuitively, I would think it implies exchangeability holds within each value of the confounding variable.

Comment: Maybe you answered your own question by now... But I don't quite see where the difficulty is. A continuous variate $B$ can be considered as the approximation of a discrete-ordinal one with a very large number of values (in practice this is always the case). Conditional exchangeability given $B$ then means that we consider (the probability of) two units to be exchangeable only if their $B$ values lie in the same small interval, $B\in(b-\Delta b, b+\Delta b)$. Maybe a nice article by Lindley & Novick, https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1176345331 can shed some light.